# Does dead(unreachable) redis sentinel count?

Tags: redis

I'm curious if dead(unreachable) sentinel processes are taken into account when calculating majority for the redis failover. For example, if I had three sentinels + Redis Master in node A and three sentinels + Redis Slave in node B, if node A completely goes offline, would Redis slave B be promoted to master? Majority vote(N/2 +1) would mean 4 sentinels agreed, but since three sentinels in node A are dead, will they count as part of N?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, dead sentinels count. Otherwise, if the connection between A and B is broken, you'll get a brain split problem.

In order to ensure HA, you need to deploy at least three nodes, each runs a sentinel instance.